# Should I use fp16 tensors to utilize tensor core?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, hardware

I am trying to utilize the V100 machine on AWS. The official site says that it provides over 100TFLOPS for machine learning application, but it seems not working that faster than the 1080ti I have been used.

Recentely, I found an article that says tensor core operates on fp16 tensor.

So, should I specify the dtype for tensor, like

`tensor_a = torch.tensor([1.,2.,3.], dtype=torch.float16)`

instead of:

`tensor_a = torch.tensor([1.,2.,3])`?

Comment: Are you sure your bottleneck is in the model? And, yes, you'd need mixed precision. Consider using [apex](https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex) from NVIDIA.

Comment: Hi, it is very hard to tell you what might be the bottleneck without seeing the code. Can you provide the code you run on the V100? `fp16` is notoriously a pain for backprop, as @Berriel suggests, look into NVIDIA apex, it makes your life a whole lot easier for mixed precision training.

Comment: Hi, @iacolippo,
Thank you for the response. It was just a simple gan.
Today I tried wrapping the network with apex.amp, and i succeed to make it a lot faster. It was just wonderful.

Comment: And thank you very much, @Berriel. You saved my day.

Comment: Hey, glad to know! Would you mind to share the speed-up you got? If you are feeling generous, you can even answer your own question showing what you did :) It would certainly benefit more people.